# Creating Incoming Search Terms for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A look at the following image:

[image: incoming search terms image]

you will see **Incoming Search Terms** before the footer, with each term links back to that page. This increases search engine ranking, and is a huge boost to traffic.

I wonder how can we implement this in an Rails app.

Comment: @Victor that wasn't a smart move.  Next time, snap an image of the part of the website you wish to emulate.  Unless you actually are a spammer, in which case...

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: Your human anti spam algorithm needs some fix. I changed the link to another Wordpress site about Rails.

Comment: @Will: I changed the link to another WP site.

Comment: @Victor this is what I was talking about

Comment: @Victor NP.  People are touchy about anything smelling slightly spammy.